# XSL unique values per node

Tags: xslt, unique

ok i have this xml

```
<roots>
<root>
    <name>first</name>
    <item type='test'><something>A</something></item>
    <item type='test'><something>B</something></item>
    <item type='test'><something>C</something></item>
    <item type='test'><something>A</something></item>
    <item type='other'><something>A</something></item>
    <item type='test'><something>B</something></item>
    <item type='other'><something>D</something></item>

</root>
<root>
<name>second</name>
    <item type='test'><something>E</something></item>
    <item type='test'><something>B</something></item>
    <item type='test'><something>F</something></item>
    <item type='test'><something>A</something></item>
    <item type='other'><something>A</something></item>
    <item type='test'><something>B</something></item>
    <item type='other'><something>D</something></item>

</root>

</roots>
```

now i need to get the unique values of each root node so far i have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
  <xsl:key name="item-by-value" match="something" use="."/>
  <xsl:key name="rootkey" match="root" use="name"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('rootkey','second')">
      <xsl:for-each select="item/something">
        <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-value', normalize-space(.)))">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

if i use "First" as the key to get only the first root i get a good result ABCD

how ever if i use "second" i only get EF  but i need the result to be ABDFE

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a complete and correct solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get `EBFAD` with a slight modification of your xsl.  The key is that if you're using the key to find the first node with this content *under the given root element*, then the key needs to be specific to the root element.  I changed the `xsl:key` to:

```
<xsl:key name="item-by-value" match="something"
 use="concat(normalize-space(.), ' ', generate-id(./ancestor::root))"/>
```

Then the `xsl:if` test becomes:

```
<xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-value', 
                  concat(normalize-space(.), ' ', generate-id(./ancestor::root))))">
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is a case where you must use a compound key.**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kSomethingByNameAndVal" match="something"
  use="concat(../../name, '+', .)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
     <xsl:for-each select=
      "item/something
             [generate-id()
             =
              generate-id(key('kSomethingByNameAndVal',
                               concat(../../name, '+', .)
                              )
                          )
             ]
      ">

       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document correctly produces the wanted result**:

**`ABCD`**

**`EBFAD`**

Answer (score 0):

I think you're pretty close. But you only want the first value of the item-by-value key which has the correct root as parent:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('rootkey','second')">
    <xsl:variable name="root" select="generate-id()" />
    <xsl:for-each select="item/something">
        <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="." data-type="text"/>
        <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-value', .)[generate-id(ancestor::root)=$root][1])">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: yeah been close for quite some time haha, and even with the [1] i still get the same results

Comment: There's no need to be rude when someone tries to help. I misunderstood the "unique" part of the question at first. I made a small change to my code to reflect the wanted result.